# Run a command inside a running python script

Tags: python, bash

I think it's a very easy thing to do but im still searching for an answer.

I have a Python script running which looks like this:

*Waiting for argument:_________*

Is there an easy way how i can start the script and automatically put some arguments in it?

Comment: so you're asking how to take user input during a python script and use it to start a bash script from within that python script?

Comment: Not exactly, it should automatically input commands. If i start a bash script with the commands or something else isn't important for me.

Comment: So you want the Python script to automatically enter the data that the user would normally type in?

Comment: yes thats exactly what i would like to do.

Comment: Then, why bother with with the user input in the first place? why not just call the bash script inside the python script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't understand u but i think u want something like

```
import os, sys 
#def some_other_functions
def cmd():
 try:
  com = raw_input('Waiting for argument:_________  ')
  #Or u can pass values as sys.args
  #like com = sys.argv[1]
  while len(com) == 0:
   com = raw_input('Waiting for argument:_________  ')
   if len(com) != 0:
     print os.system(com)
   if str(com) == 'exit':
      sys.exit()
   print '\nContinuer executing other commands or write --exit to quite the program\n'
   while True:
     com = raw_input('Waiting for argument:_________  ')
   if len(com) == 0:
     print 'Entered nothing'
   if str(com) == 'exit':
     sys.exit()
   else:
     print os.system(com)
 except Exception, e:
   print str(e)
cmd()
```